# Can't get a non-node callback library to work with Bluebird promisfy

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to use a library which doesn't implement the node convention of having a falsey value passed as the error value if no error is present, which is used for Bluebird's promisifyAll function.

The implementation of the API can be found here: https://github.com/sintaxi/dbox/blob/master/lib/dbox.js

I've implemented a custom function to get around this, but I can't get the second value to be printed to the console when using it.

```
function NoErrorPromisifier(originalMethod) {
    // return a function
    return function promisified() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        // Needed so that the original method can be called with the correct receiver
        var self = this;
        // which returns a promise
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            args.push(resolve, reject);
            originalMethod.apply(self, args);
        });
    };
}

var client = Promise.promisifyAll(app.client(token), {
  promisifier: NoErrorPromisifier
});

client.accountAsync().then(function(status, reply){
  console.log(status, reply)
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log(err)
})
```

This outputs: `200 undefined`

Whereas, using the traditional callback style:

```
client.account(function(status, reply){
  console.log(status, reply)
})
```

This outputs : `200 {{ json }}`

Any ideas?

Comment: Your function is calling `resolve()` with two arguments, not one and only the first argument comes through.

Comment: @jfriend00 Explain? I can't see where I could add code to have both arguments come through.

Comment: As others have shown you, you can put the two arguments into an array and call `resolve()` with just that array.  By specification, `resolve()` only takes a single argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original callback is called with two arguments: `status` and `reply`.

Your promisifier is replacing that callback with `resolve`, which will therefore *also* get called with two arguments, and since it only takes one, the second argument gets lost (hence the `undefined`).

Try this instead:

```
args.push(function() { resolve([].slice.call(arguments)) });
```

This will cause `resolve` to be called with an array containing the arguments with which the callback was called, for which Bluebird has the (optional) [`.spread()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html) method:

```
client.accountAsync().spread(function(status, reply){
  console.log(status, reply)
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log(err)
})
```

If you use `.then()`, it would receive the array as first argument.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for that. I would have never been able to figure that out but got your fix up and working in just seconds. Thank god for SO and thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The [*Promises/A+*](https://promisesaplus.com) standard defines the `resolve` & "`onFulfilled`" functions as accepting a single argument, the resolved value. Likewise, the *single return value* of `onFulfilled` is further propagated to the following `onFulfilled` function (attached via `then`).

```
client.accountAsync().then(function(status, reply){
```

tries to receive two augments but that is not possible, hence when logging `reply` `undefined` is logged.

Comment: I see, never knew resolve only accepted a single value, thanks!